# BigCommerce storefront apis for order

Tags: bigcommerce

Where is the documentation for /api/storefront/orders/*?
I was expecting to find it on this page.
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/cart-and-checkout/working-sf-apis

Specifically, the documentation that would cover /api/storefront/orders/:order-id
and cover the valid inputs to the querystring. I know you can pass include, with one or more of the values as a comma separated string

- payments
- lineItems.physicalItems.socialMedia
- lineItems.physicalItems.options
- lineItems.digitalItems.socialMedia
- lineItems.digitalItems.options

---

**Edit**

The checkout stencil context object used on `theme\templates\pages\order-confirmation.html` has this schema

```
{
     "order_confirmation_content": "goes in the body",
     "checkout_head": "goes in the head",
     "order": {
         "id": 206
     },
     "header_image": "for an img src attribute"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the storefront orders API can be found here:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/storefront-orders-api/order/ordersbyorderidget

However, as you mentioned, there are a few query parameters that are undocumented. Those are not officially supported, and they might be subject to change in the future. This is a case where our position is to hold off on documenting the API parameters until we've determined long-term support. Hope that helps to provide some context!

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't finding it because I was looking for a high-level category called "StoreFront APIs" which I'd expect to have Cart, Checkout and Orders...

Comment: It's a shame the the checkout object used in theme\templates\pages\order-confirmation.html isn't documented...

Comment: Hey @JJS, do you mean the checkout object that returns the order_confirmation_content, checkout_head, and order number? If you wouldn't mind sending me an email with a few more details, I'd be happy to get it added--just want to make sure I'm capturing it correctly.

Comment: Missed your edit in the original post :) But I'd still be interested to learn more about your use case.

Comment: I sent you an email